# Why does my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B no longer detect wifi networks?

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, wireless, internet

When I first began using my RPi 3 B, I was able to connect to my wifi at home without a problem. However, after attempting to connect to wifi at a different location, I have since been unable to connect to internet anywhere without an ethernet cable.I decided to download a fresh version of Jessie. Sadly, I am still facing the same problem.

When clicking on the wifi icon, I receive the "No APs found-scanning..." message, which eventually goes away without finding any networks.

My questions are: How can this problem be happening even with a fresh download? and How can I once again enable wifi capabilities for my RPi 3 B?

I have attached my RPi info below:

~ $ ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:52:50:d9  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4212 (4.1 KiB)  TX bytes:7434 (7.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:32208 (31.4 KiB)  TX bytes:32208 (31.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:07:05:8c  
      inet6 addr: fe80::12d3:be69:c87b:dc53/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:450 errors:0 dropped:450 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:28779 (28.1 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

~ $ iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

~ $ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

~ $ sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="My Network ssid"
        psk="My Network password"
}
```

~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

```
wlan0     No scan results
```

~ $ dmesg

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.50-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x3a800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 241664
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 808c5040, node_mem_map b9fa6000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2124 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 241664 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (9520->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @b9f62000 s22592 r8192 d22464 u53248
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s22592 r8192 d22464 u53248 alloc=13*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 239540
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1184 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=624 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa22082 bcm2709.serial=0xfc5250d9 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:52:50:D9 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 939064K/966656K available (6357K kernel code, 432K rwdata, 1716K rodata, 476K init, 764K bss, 19400K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff800000   (1088 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb000000   ( 944 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x807ea73c   (8074 kB)
      .init : 0x807eb000 - 0x80862000   ( 476 kB)
      .data : 0x80862000 - 0x808ce350   ( 433 kB)
       .bss : 0x808d1000 - 0x809901ec   ( 765 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000026] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000283] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001340] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001386] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.001454] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001783] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001826] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.002771] Disabling cpuset control group subsystem
[    0.002829] Initializing cgroup subsys io
[    0.002881] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.002948] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.002992] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.003034] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.003106] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003194] ftrace: allocating 21246 entries in 63 pages
[    0.052435] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.052503] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.052534] [bcm2709_smp_prepare_cpus] enter
[    0.052694] Setting up static identity map for 0x8240 - 0x8274
[    0.054355] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:1 started (0) 17
[    0.054546] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:1
[    0.054591] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.054597] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.054973] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:2 started (0) 17
[    0.055137] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:2
[    0.055158] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.055164] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.055523] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:3 started (0) 17
[    0.055654] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:3
[    0.055674] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.055680] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.055740] Brought up 4 CPUs
[    0.055839] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.055869] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.055895] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.056522] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.067396] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 3 rev 4
[    0.067767] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.068493] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.069044] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.074206] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.081054] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.081103] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.081275] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.081427] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: could not find pctldev for node /soc/gpio@7e200000/uart0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.081635] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.144611] bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at f3007000, dmachans=0x1
[    0.145223] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.145425] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.145537] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.145661] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.152007] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2017-03-03 13:42
[    0.179176] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.223893] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.224191] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.236518] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.237389] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.237527] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.237738] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.237852] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.237919] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.238170] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.238519] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.238552] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.238580] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.238607] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.239689] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.241058] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.254291] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.254615] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.256894] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.257816] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.257878] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.257907] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.260255] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.260418] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.260456] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.260528] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.263080] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory fac10000
[    0.263127] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ f3007000
[    0.284348] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 148x39
[    0.297416] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.297654] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    0.297771] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    0.297906] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.301713] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.305695] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
[    0.324505] brd: module loaded
[    0.336967] loop: module loaded
[    0.341731] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xbac80000, is_master = 0
[    0.347074] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    0.351563] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.355473] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    0.559654] Core Release: 2.80a
[    0.563460] Setting default values for core params
[    0.567309] Finished setting default values for core params
[    0.771655] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    0.775585] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.779559] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.783449] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    0.787299] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    0.791399] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xbac04000 dma = 0xfac04000 len=9024
[    0.795444] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
Non-periodic Split Transactions
Periodic Split Transactions
High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    0.814909] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    0.814960] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:415: FIQ on core 1 at 0x80448d28
[    0.818830] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:416: FIQ ASM at 0x80449098 length 36
[    0.822694] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:441: MPHI regs_base at 0xbb87e000
[    0.826619] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.830560] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.834529] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 62, io mem 0x00000000
[    0.838539] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    0.842460] Init: Power Port (0)
[    0.846465] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.850417] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.854400] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.858414] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.50-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    0.862548] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    0.867343] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.871298] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.875854] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    0.875863] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    0.875871] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    0.875906] Module dwc_common_port init
[    0.876160] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.880394] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.885023] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1200000
[    0.889198] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.893125] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.897322] sdhost: log_buf @ bac07000 (fac07000)
[    0.959208] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    0.965369] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    0.969300] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
[    1.019291] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.023527] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.027509] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.031597] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.035389] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.039630] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.043342] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.047178] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.051367] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.055897] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.059759] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    1.059910] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.062958] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    1.063568] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL32G 29.7 GiB
[    1.071329]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 < p5 p6 p7 >
[    1.078839] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    1.080518] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    1.081083] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    1.082528] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.082916] of_cfs_init
[    1.083035] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.090066] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    1.091616] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.093163] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.095944] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    1.121949] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    1.125657] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    1.193920] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.289245] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    1.293120] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    1.341936] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    1.346240] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): 4 orphan inodes deleted
[    1.349932] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): recovery complete
[    1.370175] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.373988] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:7.
[    1.385886] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.390398] Freeing unused kernel memory: 476K (807eb000 - 80862000)
[    1.489533] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    1.493445] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.498159] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.502112] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    1.667930] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 64 bits of entropy available)
[    1.676223] systemd[1]: systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)
[    1.685272] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    1.779226] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    1.805230] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.811075] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'ipv6'
[    1.819647] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    1.879666] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    1.884028] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.899858] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    1.933744] random: systemd-sysv-ge: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 69 bits of entropy available)
[    1.962658] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:52:50:d9
[    2.014371] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.020890] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.027307] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.051193] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.056543] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.059220] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    2.066172] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.094599] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.113017] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 74 bits of entropy available)
[    2.193830] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0745
[    2.198583] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.203257] usb 1-1.2: Product: MicrosoftÂ® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0
[    2.207888] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    2.219981] input: Microsoft MicrosoftÂ® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0 as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:045E:0745.0001/input/input0
[    2.237947] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service, ignoring: Unit regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[    2.252348] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.258115] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.263498] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    2.274258] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    2.279589] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    2.289995] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft MicrosoftÂ® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input0
[    2.302216] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    2.308119] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    2.320472] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    2.324382] input: Microsoft MicrosoftÂ® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0 as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:045E:0745.0002/input/input1
[    2.338322] systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
[    2.350375] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    2.356191] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-mmcblk0p6.device...
[    2.368501] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
[    2.379666] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft MicrosoftÂ® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input1
[    2.393630] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
[    2.400148] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    2.413760] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    2.420279] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    2.434110] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    2.440358] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    2.453046] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    2.458857] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    2.470548] input: Microsoft MicrosoftÂ® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0 as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2/0003:045E:0745.0003/input/input2
[    2.483206] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    2.489347] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
[    2.501661] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    2.507275] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    2.518626] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    2.524106] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    2.535176] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    2.539755] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft MicrosoftÂ® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input2
[    2.550762] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    2.562280] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    2.567654] systemd[1]: Starting system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    2.579300] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    2.584658] systemd[1]: Starting Increase datagram queue length...
[    2.629828] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    2.670222] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    2.675611] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    2.689960] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    2.705566] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    2.753144] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    2.770111] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    2.787776] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    2.797737] systemd[1]: Starting system-autologin.slice.
[    2.812244] systemd[1]: Created slice system-autologin.slice.
[    2.817906] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    2.822508] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[    2.837319] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    2.847109] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.854349] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    2.866833] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    2.877433] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    2.889298] systemd[1]: Started Increase datagram queue length.
[    2.914971] systemd[1]: Started Restore / save the current clock.
[    2.930181] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    2.942392] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    2.950559] systemd[1]: Time has been changed
[    2.980566] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[    3.071483] systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
[    3.129334] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    3.179637] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    3.193445] systemd[1]: Mounting Configuration File System...
[    3.206872] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    3.221127] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
[    3.227040] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    3.227213] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    3.241616] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    3.419757] systemd-udevd[136]: starting version 215
[    3.774374] bcm2835-wdt 3f100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    3.790159] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
[    3.985706] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    4.132776] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.158116] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    4.310126] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: May 27 2016 00:13:38 version 7.45.41.26 (r640327) FWID 01-df77e4a7
[    4.331106] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[    4.504421] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[    4.504456] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    4.504465] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    4.504476] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    4.504492] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.504506] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.504519] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.504532] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.504546] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    4.504559] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    4.504573] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    4.504591] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.091743] systemd-journald[134]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    5.519032] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
[    5.519061] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
[    5.524592] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    5.524643] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[    5.952961] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB
[    5.952986] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[    5.952995] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    5.953012] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.953027] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.953041] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    5.953054] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[    5.953067] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[    6.600303] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: no DMA platform data
[    7.004597] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[    7.004885] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    7.036948] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   10.994653] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   10.994720] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   10.994726] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.994741] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.994752] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.994773] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.002902] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   11.002915] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   11.002920] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   11.003022] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[   11.208850] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.208864] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.208879] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.669073] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  806.010169] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  806.010783] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[  828.029104] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down
```

Comment: Any chance you knocked the little ceramic antenna off the board? Without a proper case, that part is very vulnerable and easily damaged. That would explain the lack of response with a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a long shot but are you maybe using an inappropriate power supply? i had this problem when i first bought my RPI3 B, and realzied that for some reason, the issue was actually due to my power supply. I was using my old RPI2 B power supply which does not meet the minimum requirements for RPI3 B.